# How to run php code into .html file under Nginx?

Tags: nginx

How can I allow nginx to parse php code into a file with .htm extension, at a specific directory?

I need this, because I migrated from apache, and changing all file extensions would be a big headache.

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This snippet from default nginx.conf, replace `.php` to `.htm` in `location ...` and enjoy.

```
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    root           html;
#    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
#    fastcgi_index  index.php;
#    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
#    include        fastcgi_params;
#}
```